# Task queues don't work with multiple modules on development server

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up two Google App Engine modules where one of the modules is configured with Basic scaling so it can handle long-running computation.  The front-end module interacts with the user and enqueues tasks.

I need for the front-end module to be able to enqueue a task for the back-end module to pick up the task and execute it.  I've gotten it mostly to work except when I enqueue the task, it gets assigned to run in the front-end module rather than the back-end module.

The problem is in the development server environment.  On production App Engine it seems clear how to do it by simply stating in the header with the "Host" parameter:

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getDefaultQueue();
TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/longtest").param("content", content).header("Host", "nbsocialmetrics-backend");
log.info("SignGuestbookServlet taskOption " + taskOptions);
queue.add(taskOptions);
```

But in the development server, modules are addressed by port numbers rather than by module name.  I don't think using the [`<target>` parameter](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/queue#target) will work either because it also addresses the module by name rather than by port number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that the approach with the Host header DOES work on the development server with App Engine SDK version 1.9.15.

Also note this was also posted as an issue on code.google.com: [Task queues don't work with multiple modules on development server](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=10457)